# HTML to PDF using iTextSharp Library In ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, itext

I have a scenario where i want to convert `Html Template to pdf` using `iTextSharp`.Html Template is situated in the below location

> Server.MapPath("~/Template/CertificateMailTemplate.html")

This is the  below code I have tried

```
public string SendCertificate()
    {           
        try
        {
            byte[] outputstream = null;       
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var document = new Document())
                {
                    using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream))
                    {
                        document.Open();
                        using (var html = new StringReader(Server.MapPath("~/Template/CertificateMailTemplate.html")))
                        {
                            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, html);
                        }
                    }
                }

                outputstream = stream.ToArray();
            }

           //Mail sending code
            return "success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am getting the following error `The document has no pages.`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Right! I'm still too much stuck in Java 5. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `ParseXHtml` method takes a `TextReader` as the third parameter and Microsoft provides two main implementations of that class, the [`StringReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `StringReader` (which you are using) is for when you want to take an existing .Net string and read it as a sequence of characters.

The `StreamReader` (which you should switch to) is for when you want to a byte source (such as a file) and read that as a sequence of characters.

You are passing a string such as "c:\blah\blah\blah.hthml" and iTextSharp is interpreting that as your HTML and not your path to your HTML.

If you want .Net to take a wild guess at the encoding of the file you can swap your code one-for-one using the constructor [StreamReader(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx). If you know the specific encoding of the file you can use one of the overloads such as [StreamReader(String, Encoding)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, this line:

```
//Incorrect
using (var html = new StringReader(Server.MapPath("~/Template/CertificateMailTemplate.html")))
```

Should instead be:

```
//Correct
using (var html = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Template/CertificateMailTemplate.html")))
```